# How to correctly configure server and browser to avoid cors errors? Fetch API + Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, fetch-api

I was trying to make a simple api call from index.html but I kept getting an error no matter what I did.

From my understanding, the cors errors occur because I am making a call to a different server and I have to allow this in my server.

Since I was getting preflight I read that I needed to implement app.option to allow it to work but this still doesn't work.

I tried a) Setting a cors middleware
        b) using npm cors library
        c) setting app.options(), as answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379638/requesting-api-with-fetch-in-javascript-has-cors-policy-error)

I know that when using Fetch you have to be explicit about every option you choose but I seem to be missing all of them.

I ended up just calling the url in my server than fetching my server /data rout but 
I would appreciate some help configuring it correctly for future use.

Thank you!

```
Access to fetch at 'http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/api/graph/4151.json' from origin 'http://localhost:3002' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Using on client 
//index.html

```js
    <script>
      fetch('http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/api/graph/4151.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(res => console.log(res))
    </script>
```

//server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path');
const rp = require('request-promise')


const port = 3002
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
app.options('*', cors()); 
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Comment: it must be `http://services.runescape.com` to wildcard the origin.

Comment: `the cors errors occur because I am making a call to a different server and I have to allow this in my server` NO the server is getting called needs to allow who can call it.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: OP has changed the question based on the answer - but for no avail.

You don't have to set CORS headers manually if you use the cors library.

```
var cors = require('cors');


app.options('*', cors()); // Enable preflight by using this middle ware before any other route. 
app.use(cors());
```

And if the CORS should be enabled for a white list of domains, use the following options:

> ```
> var whitelist = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com']
> var corsOptions = {
>   origin: function (origin, callback) {
>     if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
>       callback(null, true)
>     } else {
>       callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Any comment on the bad side of this answer is appreciated.

Comment: its not the solution of OP's problem also not a good idea to use a wildcard. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001269/what-are-the-security-risks-of-setting-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: Thanks. But the wildcard here is not allowing all the origins. It enables CORS preflight for all routes.

Comment: yea, cors with no corsOptions does, now you updated so removing downvote.

Comment: appreciate it I made some changes in how the code, unfortunately, I am still getting an error. I removed the options in fetch since I was reading that it is added on the response not the request for allow-origin

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and point the request to your real server?